# Does running the engine without using air conditioner significantly influence battery life?

Tags: battery, ac, maintenance

Is there a tangible benefit to never using the air conditioner and will doing so increase overall battery life ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

A/C usage will not have an effect on your battery life. One does not correlate with the other. The A/C pulls most of its power directly from the engine through the accessory belt. What little power it might draw from the battery is replaced by the alternator.